# How to allow a program to be functional if the mouse is held down even while not clicking on the program itself

Tags: scrollbar, sdl-2, mousemove

(On mozilla firefox), if you click on the scroll bar on the right of the screen and hold it down, when you move up and down whilst holding the mouse down, it doesn't matter whether your mouse is on the program itself or not. You can click and hold on it and move your mouse to another display entirely and the program will still scroll up and down a webpage.

I am trying to do the same thing in SDL2 with a program, but when I made a scroll bar, as soon as I mouse off the application it stops and freezes in the `Y` location that it was before I moused off the display.

Comment: Did you [capture the mouse](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CaptureMouse) when starting the drag?  Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: You can also try `SDL_GetGlobalMouseState`.

Comment: Both of those worked. Thanks guys